# cannot show UITextview on UIview

Tags: uiview, uitextfield

I created a generator which creates for example a textfield.

```
-(UITextField *)generateTextField
{
    UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 100, 40)];
    textfield.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];

    return textfield;
}
```

Now, i am calling this function at another class with an UIView. But it doesn't show me my textfield on the screen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    SubtaskGenerator *scg = [[SubtaskGenerator alloc]init];
    UITextField * textfield = [scg generateTextField];

    [self.view addSubview:textfield];
}
```

Do I have to do it on another way?

Answer (score 0):

it is actually there, but you can't see it.
Default UITextField border width is 0.0, so you will not see it or the text field it frames.
Just add this line to generateTextField function:

```
    textfield.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
```